# pandas set index with multilevel columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multi-index

consider the below `pd.DataFrame`

```
df_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo','bar'],['one','two','three']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=18, dtype='int').reshape((-1,6)), columns=df_index)

print(df)
                     foo                    bar
     one    two     three   one     two     three
   0    7   3         8       3     6         0
   1    2   5         9       4     3         6
   2    4   2         6       6     4         5
```

I desire to set `'foo'` and all the sub-indices within it as index. How can I achieve this? I am grappling with `'set_index'`and `pd.IndexSlice` but still can't get to the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass all levels of a `MultiIndex` as a tuple. So the correct format should be:

```
df.set_index([('foo', 'one'), ('foo', 'two'), ('foo', 'three')])
```

If this is cumbersome, you could create your index using a list comprehension like:

```
idx = [x for x in df.columns if x[0] == 'foo']
print(idx)
#  [('foo', 'one'), ('foo', 'two'), ('foo', 'three')]

df.set_index(idx)
```

[out]

```
                                   bar          
                                   one two three
(foo, one) (foo, two) (foo, three)              
1          3          4              4   8     3
5          1          0              4   7     5
0          0          3              9   1     6
```

Comment: i tried df.set_index(('foo','one','two','three')) and df.set_index(('foo',('one','two','three')))..that offcourse didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
df = df.set_index(df[['foo']].columns.to_list())
```

and if you want to strip out `'foo'` from the index names

```
df.index.names = list(zip(*df.index.names))[1]
```