# How to set a column as the new index in a multi-header dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-header dataframe like this

```
         eqID            3413    2413    4213    9381
        eqName            a       b       c       d
0  1990-09-04 0:00:00    0.04    0.00    0.01    0.04
1  1990-09-04 1:00:00    0.05    0.01    0.00    0.02
2  1990-09-04 2:00:00    0.03    0.04    0.04    0.02
3  1990-09-04 3:00:00    0.06    0.08    0.09    0.04
4  1990-09-04 4:00:00    0.05    0.03    0.03    0.04
```

`eqID` and `eqName` are the first and second headers in this dataframe. I am able to rearrange the original dataframe to this format but I couldn't figure out how proceed to what I want. The expected output I am working towards:

```
                     3413    2413    4213    9381
                      a       b       c       d
1990-09-04 0:00:00   0.04    0.00    0.01    0.04
1990-09-04 1:00:00   0.05    0.01    0.00    0.02
1990-09-04 2:00:00   0.03    0.04    0.04    0.02
1990-09-04 3:00:00   0.06    0.08    0.09    0.04
1990-09-04 4:00:00   0.05    0.03    0.03    0.04
```

`eqID` and `eqName` names will be removed (note that the two rows will still be a multiheader), and the date will become a `datetimeindex`. I know how to do this for a dataframe with a single header, but how do I achieve this for a multiheader?

Comment: Something like [pandas set index with multilevel columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56788679/15497888)? `df.set_index([('eqID', 'eqName')])`?

Comment: Oh gosh, I feel so stupid. Thank you.

Comment: No worries :) Glad it was an easy fix. Add a [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) -> `df.set_index([('eqID', 'eqName')]).rename_axis(index=None)` if you want to remove the index name to match your shown output exactly.